# Windows forms C# picture gallery

Tags: c#, image, gallery

I want to create a picture gallery that when I click the button to the next picture it changes the text box (to explain what each picture is showing).

Never really used windows forms so I dont know how to approach this at all.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you change picture, identify every picture with a unique number (e.g. 0 - 9), then, check with an if statement which picture ID is it, and change text.
Example:

```
if (picNum == 0) {
picDesc.text = "This is a panda";
} else if (picNum == 1) {
picDesc.text = "This is a banana";
}
```

or use

```
switch (picNum) {
case 0: picDesc.text = "This is a panda"; break;
case 1: picDesc.text = "This is a banana"; break;
default: picDesc.text = "No picture shown"; break;
}
```

You may ask yourself, wait, how do I set up the ID?
Basically, create a variable and change it as the pictures change.

I hope I helped you, if so upvote this post and mark it as the best answer.